# Sample about RESTful and Shiro Integration

Tags: java, rest, shiro

I am developing a Java web application using RESTful as web service. And now I want to apply Apache Shiro to secure my application. The mechanism is: after user logged in successfully, a token (combined from username, password and logged time) will be returned to client. Then every single REST request will attach this token to authenticate at server (no need to authorize). But now I dont know how to configure to accept this.
And by the way, could you please give me any sample about Shiro & RESTful integration? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the REST application and the Java web application are the same Webapp, then you only need to check subject.isAuthenticated().  Use a session cookie without the password or username (it isn't a good idea to be passing around the password as it could be stolen).

Most of this behavior comes by default if both parts are in the same Webapp.

In your REST method you'd have something like:

```
Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
if(subject == null || !subject.isAuthenticated()) {
     return 401; // Not Authorized
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @Stephen. Yes, the Java web application and the REST one share the same webapp. The authentication code on server processes on that session cookie. But my REST application is a mobile app, so I am not sure that I can use session cookie on it. I prefer using a token (generated from username and password) and attach it on every single request. As a result, I need to re-implement the authentication step and cannot re-use the old one.
Anyway, your hint may help me a lot, and I will give it a try on that way.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above response, you can send back a token (session-id) from your REST Server, post successful login. Your iOS/Android application will then need to store this, and send this with every REST request it makes. Here is sample of what your post login REST response can be:

```
session-start-timestamp: 1394683755389,
session-timeout: 1800000,
session-id: "068C8E0E289788A7ABC5FE47B2CC0D28"
```

The session-id will be maintained by your REST Server, and its TTL will be reset every time a new request with this id comes in.

On browsers, this id gets sent automatically. For your case, you would want to send it explicitly with each HTTP request (which is what REST request is)

Hope this helps